# How to identify Meteor on a page?

Tags: meteor

I want to write a small chrome plugin to notify me if meteor is used on a page I visit. What is the best way to detect meteor on a page?

I planed to probe the existence of `window.__meteor_runtime_config__` or is there a better way?

Comment: Do you have reasons to believe your suggested method will not work?

Comment: Nope :-) Works so far. But my sample group is not terrible big.

Comment: Can you find a way to *circumvent* this particular check? Is that done on a regular base, i.e., is "avoiding meteor to be recognised" ever asked on SO ? If both "no" then your suggestion should be enough, unless you want to build a plugin for the *very* paranoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for the existence of `Meteor.release` itself is probably best.

This expression always returns true when run on a Meteor app all the way back to somewhere in the 0.5.x version range. It will return false elsewhere.

```
typeof(Meteor) != "undefined" && (typeof(Meteor.release) == "string" || Meteor.release === null)
```

ie

```
if(typeof(Meteor) != "undefined" && (typeof(Meteor.release) == "string" || Meteor.release === null)) {
    console.log("this is a meteor app!");
}
```

#### How it works

`Meteor.release` usually contains the version of Meteor used (hence the string check). If its built using the `devel` branch of Meteor on github the value is `null` (very very rare).

Using `window.__meteor_runtime_config__` is probably okay too. I can't recall to what versions it is compatible with. Because it uses the `__` notation there's no guarantee it will work in future versions, though.

Comment: Perfect. Thx for the detailed explanation!
Funny thing: "If its built using the devel branch of Meteor on github the value is null (very very rare)." First site I checked: respond.ly - null, probably build from devel branch :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you use Google Chrome's Extension store? I am personally using https://wappalyzer.com which detects whatever the language/framework a page is using. More secure websites will hide their tech, but for vast majority it is pretty useful.

Check it :)